# cannot convert string type to bool c++

Tags: c++, string, boolean, type-conversion

I wrote this code from a tutorial to learn the `toupper` function, but when ran I get a compile time error `cannot convert string type to bool` for the while statement. Is there another way to approach this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

char toupper(char numb);

int main()
{
    char c;

    int w = 0;
    string anArray[] = {"hello world"};

    while (anArray[w])
    {
        c = anArray[w];

        putchar (toupper(c));
        w++;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the actual `string` type. This is C++ not C.

`string anActualString = "hello strings";`

You're confusing the classic *array of characters* necessary to implement strings in C and the ability to use actual *strings* in C++.

**Also, you cannot do `while (anArray[w])` because the while() tests for boolean true or false.** `anArray[w]` is a string, not a boolean `true` or `false`. Also, you should realize that anArray is just a string array of size 1, the way you posted it. Do this instead:

```
int w = 0;
string aString = "hello world";

while (w < aString.length()) // continue until w reaches the length of the string
{
    aString[w] = toupper(aString[w]);
    w++;
}
```

The neat thing about strings in C++ is that you can use the `[]` on them as if they were regular arrays.

Comment: Actually, anArray[w] is a string in the original post. anArray is initialized to an array of strings of size 1. So, anArray[0] is the string, and anArray[1] is beyond the end of the array.

Comment: so in c they used arrays for mainly a series of numbers or characters. and now in c++ they evolved that to strings

Comment: @Adosi: Can you edit your answer to correct it regarding anArray[w]? Probably should say something like: "anArray[0] is the string..."

Comment: @TheStache: Yes, c-style arrays are pretty much a thing of the past in modern C++ code. Instead, you can substitute std::string for character strings and std::vector<> for collections of everything else. Also familiarize yourself with other collections (set, map, list), but vector is the drop-in for c-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The sample looks as they might have wanted to type

```
char anArray[] = { "hello world" };
```

or

```
char anArray[] = "hello world";
```

instead of the original

```
string anArray[] = { "hello world" };
```

Like Adosi already pointed out, std::string is a more c++ like approach.